# How to enable page-preaks in tables with captions?

Tags: libreoffice-writer, openoffice-writer, caption

When I add a caption to a table, no matter the table's settings, the table goes to next page.
I want instead it to respect the text flow and just go to the next page when needed.
If I do not add the table caption I get the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug in libreoffice where adding a caption at the bottom of an image/table trigger the "Keep with next paragraph" option.
Either add the caption at the top or manually change that option after having added the caption at the bottom.

More details:

- http://en.libreofficeforum.org/node/5853
- https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=34957

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the `Table` paragraph style is modified. Writer applies that paragraph style to Table captions by default. To check this:

1. open the `styles and formatting` window (hit `F11`),
2. select paragraph styles (leftmost button),
3. select `applied styles` from the combo box at the button,
4. right-click on the `Table` style entry;
5. from the context menu, select `Modify...`;
6. Open the `Text Flow` tab;
7. Check if inserting a page break is set in the `Breaks` section.

Comment: Thank you but actually the case I was facing is a bug in libreoffice, please see the other answer.

Comment: Ok, thanks for sharing this info! You may accept your answer to mark this question as solved (but i'm not sure how much "karma" is required to accept own answers...).